# Subversion commit hook multiple project repository set version to concrete project

Tags: svn

in our repository are many project

```
Repository
    ProjectA
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    ProjectB
        trunk
        branches
        tags
    ...
```

Now we have to add revision number to projectA and we want to be changed only if somebody modify the source code for projectA/trunk not in the other case(edit ProjectB, branches, etc. )

Is it posible to do it in one commit? (Maybe with pre commit hook? Or some other way?)
Or is it possible create  separate repository with history from our main repository?

I was look here, and i think how to do complicated post commit hook, which will do this editation and send new commit with changed version. But I am trying find better solution.